# How to add Personal Data in the Metadata field of my workout using swift?

Tags: swift, metadata, healthkit, watchos

I'm new in swift.
I have a problem that I don't find the solution.

I would like to add personnal data (the arrows count from my motionManager class) in the metadata field of my workout.

What should I add in my code to do this, please ?

```
// MARK: Properties
let motionManager = MotionManager() 
let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
var builder: HKLiveWorkoutBuilder!
weak var delegate: WorkoutManagerDelegate?
var session: HKWorkoutSession?

// MARK: WorkoutManager
func startWorkout() {
    let typesToShare: Set = [ HKQuantityType.workoutType()  ]
    let typesToRead: Set = [  HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!   ]
    healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: typesToShare, read: typesToRead) { (succ, error) in
        if !succ { }
    }
    let workoutConfiguration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
    workoutConfiguration.activityType = .archery
    workoutConfiguration.locationType = .unknown

    do {
        session = try HKWorkoutSession(healthStore: healthStore, configuration: workoutConfiguration)
        builder = session?.associatedWorkoutBuilder()
    } catch {
    }
    builder.dataSource = HKLiveWorkoutDataSource(healthStore: healthStore, workoutConfiguration: workoutConfiguration)
    session?.startActivity(with: Date())
    builder.beginCollection(withStart: Date()) { (succ, error) in
        if !succ { }
    }    
    motionManager.startUpdates()
}

func stopWorkout() {
    if (session == nil) {  return   }
    motionManager.stopUpdates()        
    print("****** END ****** ARROWS COU%NT : \(motionManager.arrowsCount)")
    
    let quantity = HKQuantity.init(unit: HKUnit.count(), doubleValue: Double(motionManager.arrowsCount))

//      WHAT SHOULD I DO TO SAVE QUANTITY IN METADATA OF THE WORKOUT ?

    session?.end()
    builder.endCollection(withEnd: Date()) { (success, error) in
        self.builder.finishWorkout { (workout, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.session = nil
                self.builder = nil
            }
        }
    }
    session = nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your builder has an `addMetadata` function. Call it passing a `[String: Any]`

```swift
builder.addMetadata(["YourKey": quantity])
```